# how to pass a Observable as parameter of an intent in android

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-intent

I have a problem in my android application I am using a java class called
Observable to manupular a socket though I n getting to pass the class that manupula it as a parameter to another class q contains a graphical interface through intent.

code below:

public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    EditText ip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtIp);
    EditText porta = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPorta);
    String txtIp = ip.getText().toString();
    int txtPorta = Integer.parseInt(porta.getText().toString());
    Conexao conexao = new Conexao(txtIp, txtPorta);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Janela.class);
    intent.putExtra("MyClass",conexao);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

thanks for listening

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving this is through `Serializable` interface. First, make your Observable Class implement Serializable interface. Then create intent just as you did (but in `putExtra` method send the instance of Observable). And after that, call `intent.getSerializableExtra("MyClass");` in your targeted activity.

Comment: Anoher option to achieve this would be `Parcelable`... For the differences between the two, take a look [here](http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/)